# Unit testing realistic Android classes. Test environment, the lifecycle, and responses

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

There seems to be no end to the number of posts discussing how to unit test completely unrealistic things.

An abundance of tutorials, videos etc outline what unit tests are and how you do them. There do not however seem to be many (if any) resources which outline how to test something real.

After all.. in reality the 'units' that we are testing are generally significantly more complex than a method taking inputs and giving an output.

I am working with Android at the moment and was investigating how to unit test my application.
My application is essentially made up of views and server requests. You click button x and it changes the view displayed. You click button y and it loads data from the server and populates a list.

Below is some source code. I have essentially pieced together an example setup which demonstrates the things that are confusing (to me). The things that I find conceptually difficult to unit test.

```
public class ChainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private PRFragmentTabHost mTabHost;

public GetChainResponse.Data responseData;

Integer chainId; //ref to chain we are getting - passed in


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the chain id we are getting
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    chainId = extras.getInt("chainId");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    //Set up the tabs
    mTabHost = (PRFragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Details").setIndicator("Details", null), ChainDetailsFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Pictures").setIndicator("Pictures", null), PicturesFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Cats").setIndicator("Cats", null), CatsFragment.class, null);

}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Initiate the data load
    loadChainData();
}


//Method loads the chain data
public void loadChainData(){

    PRAPIInterface apiService = ApiService.getInstance();

    Integer limit = 4;

    apiService.getChain(chainId, limit, new Callback<GetChainResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void success(GetChainResponse pr, Response response) {

            lastData = System.nanoTime();

            //Save the response data
            responseData = pr.data;

            //Get the current tab and pass the loaded data to it
            String currentTabTag = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
            DataLoadedInterface currentTab = (DataLoadedInterface) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentTabTag);
            currentTab.dataLoaded(responseData, false);
        }


        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.w("Failed", "Failed" + retrofitError.getUrl());
            Log.w("Failed", "Failed" + retrofitError.getBody());
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

So.. I am aware of Roboeletric, Robotium etc and other libraries that are available for testing on Android. I am however looking for conceptual advice.

Android provides `ActivityUnitTestCase`

I can subclass this and setup a test for my activity.

### Part 1

In principle I could test my onCreate by verifying that mTabHost is not null BUT I don't want to make it publicly available, nor do I want to have a getter to its value.

I figured that I could test the existence of my fragments but i can in fact not. Because the activity runs in 'isolation' it seemingly does not actually create the fragments for the tabs.

### Part 2

Next is `onStart`. This calls another method. It has no return value. I cant test a response.
It is however important that i test that onStart we load our initial data..

Within `loadChainData` I could set a Boolean indicating that I am loading data and verify this but a coworker could just set this Boolean to true by default and my test would pass.

Furthermore I don't want to test loadChainData 'again'.. I will be testing this method anyway. One idea that springs to mind is stubbing out loadChainData and verifying that it is called and leaving it at that. This however seems to be difficult to do with Android (anyone..?) and does not really fit with the sentiment that testing should be fun.

### Part 3

`loadChainData` loads some data from the server using retrofit. Because in reality this method executes asynchronously there is again no response from this method. I have found an appropriate way of returning mock data by swapping out the retrofit client but doing this swapping is not apparently simple.

At the moment I use a singleton for my ApiService. I want to essentially replace what is built the first time this singleton is called. There are potential complex solutions for this like using a Dependency injection library (like Dagger) but given what I want to achieve I feel that there should be a much simpler way of doing this.

My initial thoughts are that if the application could be instantiated with say a test flag. The singleton would return the test client. Alternatively it would default to the real client. This in my mind smells a little.. could someone explain what the smell is, and how one could appropriately resolve it?

Even if the above was considered a fair suggestion there seems to be no easy way to actually do it with ActivityUnitTestCase.

### Part 4

Finally is `onActivityResult`.
Again, there is no response.
This time the method in question interacts with other units elsewhere. Units that act differently within the constraints of ActivityUnitTestCase anyway.

I could wrap my manipulation of the support fragment manager, mock my wrapper, return a mocked fragment, verify that its onActivityResult method is called.. but again this seems incredibly tough to do. Furthermore this adds complexity to my code to allow *something* to be testable. I have no interest in increasing complexity just to test..

### So..

Does anyone with real experience unit testing on mobile have any insight on how to appropriately tests a class such as this one. As you can see it is not really a case of  'put 2 in, does 4 come out' :)

A lot of resources mention how testing is underdone. This is why :) Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

T

Comment: I agree with you in general. I tried using Roboguice for DI and Mockito for replacing with mocks and it is a bit better, however I detest this. I do not have much experience in mobile or even OOP, but I think it should be much easier to do such testing. I hope somebody with real experience will give an answer that I can use too :)

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate`

I would test in two ways, one using some form of `AndroidTestCase` this would allow the testing of extras you send in the Bundle.
( I would add error handling to throw an error if the extra is not present )
( I would change loadChainData() to take chainId as a paramater )

To test your tabs are instantiated correct I would use `espresso` for an Acceptance test to validate your views are present.

`onStart`

There is no [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) here and so you cannot test the service methods are called. You would want to test `getChain` is called. What happens when you create that service, could you do it in the constructor?
 ( I would move away from the Activity here and encapsulate all behaviour from `onStart` in some other class [perhaps MVC could help] that way you aren't constrained by the lifecycle.
 ( I would also add another layer of callback's on top of Volley in to the Activity, that way you can test your listeners return the correct success or failure, but you don't have to worry about the tabs [the activity ui]).

If you really wanted to test asynchronisity (which I wouldn't advise) you can use Espresso and that can help you manage the test to still get callbacks [see custom resource idoling](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Using_registerIdlingResource_to_synchronize_with_custom_resource).

`onActivityResult`

I believe using Robolectric you could pass it a Mockito mock fragment manager in order to return you a stub fragment and validate the behviour of the  the fragment tab host, then you would call `onActivityResult` yourself: whether testing this actually gives you any benefit is another question.

Overall testing lifecycle methods is like testing anything else, for it to be testable you need to abstract away any ideas of threading, you need to be in control of your dependencies and I find the closer you adhere to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) the easier testing is. In the wake of these stumbling blocks, this is why [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), [InstrumentationTests](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation) and [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso) where created.

In summary sorry, there is no straight forward answer here, you have to ask yourself - do I get any benefit from testing these things, am I testing my code or am I testing the framework, what is the cost benefit of testing this Activity does it actually encumber future changes rather than gain me confidence.